How do I access the /root folder?
How do I enter the /root folder, not the / folder?
I need to go into the /root folder to print the contents of the /root folder on a file in the home(~) folder.
I tried to do 'sudo cd root'
Here's the response:
sudo: cd: command not found
sudo: "cd" is a shell built-in command, it cannot be run directly.
sudo: the -s option may be used to run a privileged shell.
sudo: the -D option may be used to run a command in a specific directory.

I also tried to do sudo ls root but it didn't work.
[sudo] password for piyush: 
snap

I tried attaching a screenshot but the website didn't allow me to post images. I am a beginner so please don't go too heavy with the answer.

If you want the contents of /root, you need sudo ls /root.

"I also tried to do sudo ls root but it didn't work."... It did and it showed the directory or file which didn't start with "."(dot). If you want to list all files try using sudo ls -a /root or sudo ls -full /root.

Related: How to enter a directory with the 'cd' command if it has 700 permission and is not owned by me?

Try:
   exec sudo -i
   ls -a /root > /home/piyush/filesroot.txt
   chmod -R 777 /home/piyush/filesroot.txt
   exit


Thanks, I removed my downvote; however all you need is ls -a >~"$SUDO_USER"/filesroot.txt, you're already in /root because of sudo -i, SUDO_USER will expand to the right username and the file will be created in the user's home directory; also I'd advise chown "$SUDO_USER": ~"$SUDO_USER"/filesroot.txt instead of leaving ownership to root and assigning unneeded execute permissions


sudo su
Enter the password.
cd ~/

You need to have the appropriate permissions and password. If you don't, contact your system administrator and have them do what you need.

sudo -i is a better way to get a root shell, and it will also change directory to /root automatically. Then of course at least ls -a to list all files in there.

One would hope that the user has access to their own password.
